# Computing remainder without using modulus operator F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have implemented my code which is basically to compute remainder in two numbers without using modulus operator however, I am stuck in a situation which is just hectic. I know the logic however I am newbie in f# and dont know how to implement it.

```
let rec modulus a b =
if b = 0 Console.WriteLine("Sorry Wrong Divisor")
let bool neg = a < 0
a = abs a
b = abs b
modulus(val-divisor,divisor)
```

All I know is I am getting a pretty basic mistake here, Any help,

Comment: The code as written is hard to understand.  The indentation is incorrect and I suspect the equals operator is misused

Comment: Besides what Tomas Petricek has pointed out, you create a value called `neg` (and you don't need to say `let bool` there: `let neg = a < 0` is enough). But you never use that value. You probably intended to have an `if` statement in there somewhere. And `if` statements in F# are written `if (condition) then (value-if-true) else (value-if-false)`. The `else` is ONLY optional if the `value-if-true` resolves to the `unit` type. If you don't understand what that means yet, don't worry about it, just remember that the `else` part of an `if` statement is almost never optional.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first step towards getting this to work is to fix your indentation and turn your sketch into valid F# code that actually compiles and runs - that should help you get to the next step, which is to fix the logic of the implementation.

A minimal code that is similar to yours and actually runs looks like this:

```
let rec modulus value divisor : int =
  printfn "value=%d, divisor=%d" value divisor
  if divisor = 0 then Console.WriteLine("Sorry Wrong Divisor")
  let neg = value < 0
  let value = abs value
  let divisor = abs divisor
  modulus (value-divisor) divisor

modulus 10 5
```

- I fixed the indentation - F# is indentation sensitive, so this matters.
- I replaced your `a = abs a` with `let` - the `let` keyword defines a new variable, hiding the existing one (as you cannot mutate existing variables - they are immutable in F#)
- I renamed your variables to consistently use `divisor` and `value` names
- I added `printfn` so that you can see how the function runs (it will get into an infinite loop, because it currently never checks for the termination condition!)
- I had to add type annotation `: int` to say that the result will be `int` - as your function never returns, this is required (but you can remove it once you fix this)

Comment: Thank you so much Its all clear now. Yes indentation is so sensitive in F# as there are no braces involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate modulus in simpler way

```
let modulus a b=
    if b = 0.0 then failwith "Cannot divide by zero"
    a - b * truncate(a / b);
```

Comment: My requirement was using a recursive function however thanks

Comment: Bad coding. You generally can't reliably compare floating point numbers with the equality operator.